# Using Qt Designer and Python to open a window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am new to Qt Designer and I want to do a simple thing: open the window of the GUI that I created (ImageViewer.py); but it doesn't work. So if you have any idea why I can't open the GUI, please help me.

This is ImageViewer.py:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import ImageViewerUI

class ImageViewer(QMainWindow,ImageViewerUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def main(self):
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = ImageViewer()
    imageViewer.main()
    app.exec_()
```

and ImageViewerUI.py:

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ImageViewerUI.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(797, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.imageLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.imageLabel.setFont(font)
        self.imageLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.imageLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("imageLabel"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 797, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFile"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionOpen"))
        self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExit"))
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.imageLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello world !!", None))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File", None))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open", None))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit", None))
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the error, which you facing with when running your application

Comment: I don't see anything, the program not open the window !

Comment: any output to the console, maybe?

Comment: @ronyco. I tried your code, and it works fine for me. Are you sure you're running the script correctly - i.e. `python ImageViewer.py`? What platform are you on?